# How can I extract and separate double values from String?

Tags: java, string, android-studio, double, extract

Let's say that I receive a java String message = "a=5.31,b=2.004,c=3.1230" that sends 3 variables I want in a single String message.

How can I extract the accurate value of a,b,c and then have 3 double OR string variables x,y,z hold the values of a,b,c respectively? Preferably, I'd like this to be able to handle any number of decimal places (or at the very least up to 4 dp).

I've read the thread on using regex to extract numbers from String messages, but I could not find a way to separate the resulting numbers after passing it through the matcher.

Is there a library I could import for this?

I am currently using Android Studio supporting API 21 and above for this problem.

Comment: Use the `split` method of the `String` class twice.  Once with `,` as the argument and once with `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fragile, draft solution could involve a pattern/matcher combination with iteration and back-references, as well as the parsing utility [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) from `Double`.

Something like:

```
String test = "a=5.31,b=2.004,c=3.1230";
//                          | [letter(s)]=
//                          |    | group 1: digits and dots
//                          |    | 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+=([\\d.]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
// iterating on findings
while (m.find()) {
    // back-reference
    String match = m.group(1);
    // trying to parse combination of digits and dots as double
    try {
        double d = Double.valueOf(match);
        System.out.printf("Found double: %f%n", d);
    }
    // handling non-parseable combinations of digits and dots
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // TODO handle
        System.out.printf("Couldn't parse %s as double.%n", match);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Found double: 5.310000
Found double: 2.004000
Found double: 3.123000
```

**Note**

The output pads additional `0`s because of the default `printf` representation.

Comment: Could I ask what the \\w does for the regex?

Comment: @Glenn when ever considering Java patterns, [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is your bible. You'll see in that page that the `\w` constructs signifies: "A word character: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`".

Comment: How should I go about separating the values into 3 different variables rather than one variable d? Should I use a for loop for that and change the try catch?

Comment: @Glenn add them to a collection? You can even add the key-value (e.g. `a` -> `5.31`) to a map if you enclose the representation of the key in a group (would become group 1, the value would become group 2). Plenty of choices.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
String message = "a=5.31,b=2.004,c=3.1230";
String[] kvpairs = message.split(",");
Double x = Double.valueOf(kvpairs[0].split("=")[1]);
Double y = Double.valueOf(kvpairs[1].split("=")[1]);
Double z = Double.valueOf(kvpairs[2].split("=")[1]);
System.out.println(z);
```

[prints "3.123"](https://ideone.com/9DJ1km)

Comment: If my String message has more characters and I remove the commas, e.g. String message = "Values received: a=5.31 b=2.004 c=3.1230", would this still work? I'm assuming I would have to change message.split() in line 2 to something else in that case.

Comment: In that case, [Mena's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925406/214525) above is more robust as it identifies all numerical values in the string regardless of the text before it and regardless of the seperator.

Answer (score 0):

using split method of String:

```
Arrays.asList(line.trim().split(",")).stream.map(w -> w.split("=")[1].trim())...
```